# Ionic Insights: Device information unavailable

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having following error although I have already installed required plugins.
What could the problem about?

```
 I : [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Native: tried calling Device.platform, but the Device plugin is not installed.", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic.cloud.min.js (1)
 I : [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Install the Device plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device'", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic.cloud.min.js (1)
 I : [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Ionic Insights: Device information unavailable.", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic.cloud.min.js (11)
 I : [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Ionic Insights: Could not send insights.", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic.cloud.min.js (11)
```

index.html

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>


<!-- ionic cloud js -->
<script src="lib/ionic.cloud.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->

<!-- libs -->
<script src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

**Your system information:**

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1

Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1

Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20

OS:
Node Version: v4.4.1

Comment: What command you're trying to run?